# What does myVar = {} do?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand line 1; what does this line do?

```
phonebookEntry = {};

phonebookEntry.name = 'Oxnard Montalvo';
phonebookEntry.number = '(555) 555-5555';
phonebookEntry.phone = function() {
  console.log('Calling ' + this.name + ' at ' + this.number + '...');
};

phonebookEntry.phone();
```

Comment: it is to specify that `phonebookEntry` is an object, in order to attatch properties to it. [MDN | Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: In a JavaScript expression, `{}` just creates a new empty object.

Answer (score 4):

this line creates a new empty object, without properties

```
phonebookEntry = {};
```

without it you cannot do this:

```
phonebookEntry.name = 'Oxnard Montalvo';
phonebookEntry.number = '(555) 555-5555';
```

in javascript there is another way to declare an equivalent object:

```
phonebookEntry = {
    name : 'Oxnard Montalvo',
    number : '(555) 555-5555',
    phone : function() {
      console.log('Calling ' + this.name + ' at ' + this.number + '...');
    }
};

phonebookEntry.phone();
```

reference: [MDN | Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: hey , I tried that ... but codecademy says SyntaxError: Unexpected token http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-9Sgpi/2/1?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Comment: @SantiagoHernández now it works to me .... Maybe codecademy is just being a little bit buggy ... -_-

Answer (score 2):

This `phonebookEntry = {};` is an empty object, without any properties.

Actually, this is equivalent to this `phonebookEntry = new Object();`

You could validate this as simple as below:

```
typeof(phonebookEntry)
```

which will output `"object"`.

In `JavaScript` we have the ability of creating empty objects like the above and later to attach any property that is meaningful to us, like below:

```
phonebookEntry.name = 'Oxnard Montalvo';
```

or equivalently

```
phonebookEntry["name"] = 'Oxnard Montalvo';
```

Furthermore, the latter is called *bracket notation*.

As it is stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), where you will find a more thorough and detailed approach on this topic:

> JavaScript is designed on a simple object-based paradigm. An object is
>   a collection of properties, and a property is an association between a
>   name and a value. A property's value can be a function, in which case
>   the property is known as a method. In addition to objects that are
>   predefined in the browser, you can define your own objects. This
>   chapter describes how to use objects, properties, functions, and
>   methods, and how to create your own objects.

In the above code, we have defined the property `name`, with key `name` and value 'Oxnard Montalvo'.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the standard approach and would clear more of your concepts.

```
function PhonebookEntry(name, number){
var privateName = name;
var privateNumber = number;
this.phone = function() {
  console.log('Calling ' + privateName + ' at ' + privateNumber + '...');
};
};
phonebookEntry = new PhonebookEntry('Oxnard Montalvo', '(555) 555-5555');
phonebookEntry.phone();
phonebookEntry1 = new PhonebookEntry('Montalvo', '(222) 222-2222');
phonebookEntry1.phone();
```

Comment: `this.name` and `this.number` don't exist on your constructed object (because `var` is not the same as `this`)

Comment: With your new edit you now don't need the `var` lines at all, because you can just access the identifiers used as function parameters :)

Comment: no, this is just a sample, but ideally there would be setter function that will assign the parameters to the private variables which might have some validations of data.